# Changing UITabBar Text

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I've been trying to figure out how to change my UITabBar's text. I'm trying this but it's not working, what should I do?

```
- (id)init 
{
    UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:nil] image:nil tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem = theItem;
    return self;  
}
```

Comment: What? `initWithTitle:` requires an NSString as an instance as the title... What even are you trying to change? Also, what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: Also, there are very few places (in modern Xcode) where you should be doing UI-component setup in a method called simply 'init'. Can you elaborate on where you are placing this code, and what exactly you are trying to accomplish? It may be possible entirely in the storyboard, or more implicitly through properly title'd and navItem'd view controllers.

Comment: Okay say I put @"Hello" in the initWithTitle: How can I change the text of @"Hello"?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the title to an instance of a font instead of a string.

```
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Title" image:nil tag:0];
```

Comment: I know that but what if I wanted to change the text of @"Some Title" to a different font?

Comment: Explore UIBarItem's setTitleTextAttributes:forState: method: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007520-CH3-SW5

Comment: Okay I put this in my viewDidLoad and it crashed. [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and it crashes the app?

Comment: Pay careful attention to the APIs. Your dictionary does not have any keys.

Comment: The keys you need are documented here (linked from my previous comment's docs) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3

Comment: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont, nil]

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; it's suppose to be in my viewDidLoad right?

Comment: I suggest opening a new SO question, better named, so you can get more attention on this and it can move out of a comment thread, and marking this question answered. This will be better for any future community members searching for this problem.